# How to make a div appear on timer and disappear on click?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to complete my first project and I am new to JavaScript, I'm trying to have a div appear on the page after X amount of seconds and disappear on click and to have it loop, so if some one opens it, the div appears after the timer, on click and it disappears, and it will appear again after the timer again. I've tried @keyframes animations but they only make my div disappear. I am also doing this on codepen, so some answers might not work (I think) . I also have tried using JavaScript but to no avail, so I have been taking lessons on free code camp.org, but it is only teaching me basic JavaScript. Finally I'm gonna post a link to my pen for you guys to check out below. I'll take any constructive criticism,
as it is my first project. Sorry for the multiple edits, I've never asked a community for help before.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1drQkb0PbVE2iJKPIIdt6zk8DYoICjfDQ");
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-color:#000000;
  margin:unset !important;
  font-family:arial;
}
  .fireteam{
font-size:16px;
color:white;
}
#fireteam{
position:absolute;
display:block;
top:-20px;
right:231px; 
}
#emblem{
 height:72px;
 width:321px; 
 position:absolute;
  padding:1px 10px 1px 10px;
  right:80px;
  top:30px;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
 background: linear-gradient(304deg, #ff0000, red, #ffa500, orange, #ffff00, yellow, #008000, green, #0000ff,blue, #800080, purple,#ff0000, red, #ffa500, orange, #ffff00, yellow, #008000, green, #0000ff,blue, #800080, purple,#ff0000, red, #ffa500, orange, #ffff00, yellow, #008000, green, #0000ff,blue, #800080, purple,#ff0000, red, #ffa500, orange, #ffff00, yellow, #008000, green, #0000ff,blue, #800080, purple,#ff0000, red, #ffa500, orange, #ffff00, yellow, #008000, green, #0000ff,blue, #800080, purple,#ff0000, red, #ffa500, orange, #ffff00, yellow, #008000, green, #0000ff,blue, #800080, purple,#ff0000, red, #ffa500, orange, #ffff00, yellow, #008000, green, #0000ff,blue, #800080, purple,#ff0000, red, #ffa500, orange, #ffff00, yellow, #008000, green, #0000ff,blue, #800080, purple,#ff0000, red, #ffa500, orange, #ffff00, yellow, #008000, green, #0000ff,blue, #800080, purple,#ff0000, red, #ffa500, orange, #ffff00, yellow, #008000, green, #0000ff,blue, #800080, purple, #ff0000, red, #ffa500, orange, #ffff00, yellow, #008000, green, #0000ff,blue, #800080, purple);
    background-size: 777%  777%;

    -webkit-animation: AnimationName 70s ease infinite;
    -moz-animation: AnimationName 70s ease infinite;
    animation: AnimationName 70s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-position:0% 5%}
    50%{background-position:100% 96%}
    100%{background-position:0% 5%}
}
@-moz-keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-position:0% 5%}
    50%{background-position:100% 96%}
    100%{background-position:0% 5%}
}
@keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-position:0% 5%}
    50%{background-position:100% 96%}
    10
}

.user-name{
  font-size:21px;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  }
#user-name{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  margin-left:65px;
  margin-top:6px
}
.power-level {
  font-size:25px;
  color:yellow;
  position:relative;
  font-weight:bold;
  }
#power-level{
  margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  right:6px;
  bottom:42px;
}

.clan-name {
 font-size:17px;
 color:white;
 font-family:italic;
  }
#clan-name{
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
 margin-top:0px;
 margin-left:66px;   
}
.ghost {
position:relative;
width:42px;
height:auto;
display:inline-block;
}
#ghost{
 display:inline-block;
 position:absolute;
 top:13px;
 left:24px; 
}

.pl-icon{
 position:relative;
width:10px;
height:auto;
display:inline-block;
  }
#pl-icon{
 margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
 display:inline-block;
 position:absolute;
 right:62px;
 top:5px;
}
.triangle{
position:relative;
width:30px;
height:auto; 
}
#triangle{
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  Display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
}
.jumpship{
height:470px;
width:auto; 
}
#jumpship{
 display:inline-block;
 position:absolute;
 left:410px;
 top:150px; 
 z-index:-1; 
 animation-name: floating;
 animation-duration: 7s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes floating {
from { transform: translate(0,  0px); }
65%  { transform: translate(0, 15px); }
to   { transform: translate(0, -0px); }    
} 
#main { 
  border-top: 9px solid #FF5952;
  height:150px;
  margin:265px 0 0 0;
  width:100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index:1;
  }
#main {
  animation: cssAnimation 0s 7s forwards;
  opacity: 0; 
}

@keyframes cssAnimation {
  to   { opacity: 1; }
}
#icon-holder {
 background-color:#3B4956;
  width:35%;
  height:150px;
  opacity:0.8;  
  display:inline-block;
 }
.point{
position:relative;
width:111px;
height:auto;
float:right;
padding:3px 12px 0 0;
  }
#title { 
  height:75px;
  width:65%; 
  backdrop-filter:blur(4px);
 display:inline-block;
 position:absolute; 
}
  #title::before{
  content: "";
      background-image: url("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1lAegDNv9UA3tunXylxrW5Loomz3X2cEA");
      background-size: cover;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      opacity:0.7;    
}
  .title {
  font-size:39px;
   color:white;
  font-weight:bold; 
  text-align:left;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  top:15px;
  left:10px;
  opacity:1;
  padding-left:15px;  
  }

#message {
  height:75px;
  width:65%;
  position:absolute;
  backdrop-filter:blur(4px);
  display:inline;
  top:349px;
  background-size:cover;
}
#message::before{
  content: "";
      background-image: url("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1A38rtfR8GbdVW3R98E6PEQRRlZdBqQ6j");
      background-size: cover;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      opacity: 0.7;
}
  .message{
  font-size:21px;
  color:white;
  text-align:right;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  top:18px;
  left:10px; 
  padding-left:15px;  
}
#basement {
  background-image: url("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1wpkpK5n7Msvr4uqMme7Uk55HPOJx05H9");
  height:25px;
  width:100%;
  bottom:3px;
  padding:1px;
  position:relative;
  text-align:left;
 }
#basement {
  animation: cssAnimation 0s 7s forwards;
  opacity: 0; 
}

@keyframes cssAnimation {
  to   { opacity: 1; }
}
.dismiss {
  font-size:18px;
  color:white; 
  display:inline-block;
}
#dismiss{
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
bottom:9px;
float:center
}
.icon {
 width:42px;
 height:auto;
 display:inline-block;
 float:center;
}
#icon{
display:inline-block;
position:relative; 
width:65%;
float:right; 
bottom:1px;  
}
.director{
  font-size:21px;
  color:white; 
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  padding:4px 50px 4px 50px;
  position:relative;
}
#director{
 width:280px;
 position:relative;
float:right;
  bottom:-130px;
  right:-370px;
}
#director::before {
content: "";
background-image:url("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1wpkpK5n7Msvr4uqMme7Uk55HPOJx05H9");
background-size: cover;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
opacity: 0.65;
filter:blur(6px);
}
.friends{
  font-size:16px;
  color:white; 
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  padding:0px 15px 0px 0px;
}
#friends{
width:167px;
position:absolute;
display:inline-block;  
float:right;
bottom:20px;
right:285px; 
}
.invite{
 font-size:16px;
  color:white; 
}
#invite{
width:150px;
position:absolute;
display:inline-block;  
float:right;
bottom:20px;
right:132px;
}
.menu{
  font-size:16px;
  color:white;  
}
#menu{
 width:150px;
position:absolute;
display:inline-block;  
float:right;
bottom:20px;
right:-2px;
}
.icon2{
 width:17px;
 height:auto;
 display:inline-block;
 float:left; 
 margin-right:10px;
}
.icon3{
 width:17px;
 height:auto;
 display:inline-block;
 float:left; 
 margin-right:7px; 
}
.icon4 {
width:17px;
height:auto;
display:inline-block;
float:left; 
margin-right:7px;   
}
```

```html
<body>
  </script>
  <div id="emblem">
     <div id="fireteam"> <span class="fireteam">F I R E T E A M</span>
    </div>
    <div id="triangle"> <img class="triangle" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1PdfKbElHGA0zYoX3uU97dBMJcQRbLmOf">
    </div>
    <div id="ghost"> <img class="ghost" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1imBPZyD5tG5J6zP1OyP0D23c5IvSDT2a">
    </div>
    <div id="user-name"> <span class="user-name"> prince_of_war04</span>
    </div>
    <div id="clan-name"> <span class="clan-name">Nerf600autos</span>
    </div>
    <div id="pl-icon"> <img class="pl-icon" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1bat6pZthPyIotmXi8dcDfLChVTKYlnZY">
    </div>
    <div id="power-level"> <span class="power-level">1078</span>
    </div>
      
    </div>
  <div id="jumpship"> 
    <img class="jumpship" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1W9RVvJq0NBokWZ3u4L6x1QKbMfH6IJUW">
  </div>
 
  <div id="main">
    <div id="icon-holder">
      <img class="point" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1X2QpP_a_1-CS8doBZQ9F6Ll-_3llmOsR">
    </div>
    <div id="title">
      <span class="title"> C O N T R O L L E R</span>
    </div>

    <div id="message">
     <span  class="message">Your wireless controller is disconnected. Reconnect your wireless controller.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="basement">
   <div id="icon"> <img class="icon" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1ZHO3k7CGI_7AxJi2A0-3aMNM1sAXWHN_">
<div id="dismiss"> <span class="dismiss">Dismiss
    </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div id="director"> <span class="director"> OPEN DIRECTOR</span> 
 
  </div>
  <div id="friends"> <span class="friends">69 friends online</span>
    <img class="icon4" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1bb-rA2hDayk1T7kOpVtAkAoXU_32a-bS">
    </div>
  <div id="invite"> <span class="invite">Invite Friends</span> 
    <img class="icon2" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=18WUa8u3oToBZVmgFTT3eM_i055M8y81N">
  </div>
 <div id="menu"> <span class="menu">Menu</span> 
   <img class="icon3" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1x0iByNuEzmFjIc8-fb739t44HIya1RAc">
  </div>
</body>
```

I'll take assistance In any form can get, I greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Please show what you've tried so we can assist.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (and get a badge). Your question lacks any attempt at solving this problem on your own. The idea is for you to try to get something to work and then come here with specific problems you are unable to resolve. Taking the tour and reading about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center will provide all the information you need.

Comment: Keyframes is CSS, you probably want to use Javascript, read up on it and how to manipulate the DOM (HTML), especially read about functions, event listeners, and the settimout function.

Comment: A couple of things... Please always post your code, here at Stack Overflow, right in your question. Don't link out to it. Next, what you are trying to do can't be done with CSS, you need JavaScript for that and as @RandyCasburn indicated, we expect that you do your research and make an attempt before posting here. Then, when you do post, you'll post your attempt and a specific question about it. Right now, there really isn't any JavaScript attempt at this. As @andrralv said, you need to research functions, event listeners and `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).on( "click", function( 
event ) {
if   (!$(event.target).closest("#timer").length) {
    $("#somediv").appendTo("#timer"); 
}
$("#somediv").hide();
});
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation to your answer, otherwise it gets marked as low quality answer.